# Test if any item in array returns true?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of objects, currently I loop throught them and test them one by one, but I try to make my code more concice and easy to follow. I wonder weather there is a way, with javascript or underscore, to test if at least one item in array returns true.

```
  for (var x = 0; x < user.apilog.length; x++) {
    //test the conversion
    if(conversions[i].conditional(user.apilog[x]) ){
      //run if true
      break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `user.apilog` is an array, then you can use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var found = user.apilog.some(function (item, i) {
    return conversions[i].conditional(item);
});
```

n.b. underscore also provides a `some` method that works pretty much the same way, with the benefit that it should work on array-like objects as well as actual arrays:

```
var found = _.some(user.apilog, function (item, i) {
    return conversions[i].conditional(item);
});
```

Comment: Wow! that is sweet! I don't need IE8 support and I bet this will have better perfomance than something like underscore!

Comment: I didn't know about this before but couldn't you he just create a function check(elem, index, arr) and then call user.apilog.some(check)? edit: assuming the function checked if true or false

Comment: @pbrianq Yes, defining the function separately would certainly work, too. I'm using an anonymous function here because it's just a one-line function and defining it as a separate function might be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

With [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#some) you could simply use `_.some(user.apilog)`